# Lint-staged can't find staged files matching glob

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I'm working with NodeJS Typescript and I wanted to set `lint-staged` to validate my files before commit but it is not working. I added from a guide as following:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx, md, html}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```

The error I'm getting:

```
No staged files match any of provided globs.
```

What is the right config for my `package.json`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spaces after commas can break the globs - try removing them:

```
"*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,md,html}"
```

Comment: "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint . --fix",
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }                                                                                                                                                                 I have this but still not working why

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that space! but it did break it from recognizing the extension after it

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 2):

Becase no file in Staged changes, change one file (make sure this file has error format) => git add . => npx lint-staged