# GitHub folder has a white arrow on it and can't open

Tags: git, github

I want to have a server and client projects in the same repository.
 After finishing backend I cloned a boilerplate(client) for the frontend from another repository. It is in the same level as **src**. 
 After pushing it to github I can see a white arrow in client folder, and can't open. Following the steps [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them) I removed **.git** from client folder. But when I do

```sh
git add client
```

or

```sh
git add . 
git commit -m "commit"
```

it says that

```sh
husky > pre-commit (node v10.16.0)
i No staged files found.
On branch features
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first do:

```
git rm --cached client      # no trailing slash
git commit -m "remove client gitlink"
```

Than you can try and add `client/` again, which, since it has no .git subfolder, should include its files content.

Note that, as illustrate in [`okonet/lint-staged` issue 682](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/682) and its [README](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#how-to-use-lint-staged-in-a-multi-package-monorepo)

> If you wish to use lint-staged in a multi package monorepo, it is recommended to install [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) in the root `package.json`.

Check also your husky configuration, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57779069/6309).

---

> I've "`.gitignore`" file in client folder. Can it affect on this issue?

If nothing is added, you can check if that is because of any ignore rule with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- client/aFile_that_should_be_added
```

Comment: thanks for answer.  Actually I've tried it as well. But it didn't work, it says 
"fatal: pathspec 'client' did not match any files"

Comment: @Greg Do yu have the link of your GitHub repository?

Comment: Hi @VonC. Unfortunately it's a private from the company I am studying. But I can provide any info you want.

Comment: @Greg If you still have the gitlink (white arrow folder) on the remote GitHub repo, can you clone it back to a different local folder, and try the `git rm --cached client` there? (Plus commit and push)

Comment: Hi @VonC I still have it. Actually cloned the whole repo, but the client folder didn't appear.

Comment: @Greg In that new clone repo, can you copy your client folder (without its .git subfolder) and try your add and commit there? A push should this time push the client folder content.

Comment: Hi @VonC I'm already doing. In the meantime one question please. I've "gitingnore" file in client folder. Can it affect on this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222861/discussion-between-vonc-and-greg).

Answer (score 0):

People of the internet, I found a pretty simple solution to the problem. make sure you have a parent folder and all other folders need to be children inside that one. I was getting a white arrow on my folders and deleting the .git did not work, but putting a parent folder solved the problem in both my projects. Also for those having issues with uploading to github, here is the best article : https://www.tutsmake.com/upload-project-files-on-github-using-command-line/, make sure to change the URL in step 6.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).